# error while installing mahotas to python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, mahotas

I am using command prompt for installing Manhotas 1.1.0. I have mahotas in zip file and I have extracted it out. My procedure was:' python setup.py install' . But,its giving me error:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using pip or easy-install

You can **[REFER THIS](http://mahotas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html)**

And if you get an error of numpy.distils.core **[Refer this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pythonvision/6IZbf6cJW7M)**

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late answer, Still it may be useful.

You can download .whl package for windows from here : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mahotas

and use

```
pip install <packahename.whl>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I'll definitely try this out. Thank you so much.